# How to get this Display Template working for Dates for DisplayFor in MVC3. Trivial I think

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Think I am doing something silly here.

I have :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated,"ShortDateTime")
```

I need to display this datetime like "01/01/2013 20.13", and I wish to do it via Display Templates. I have a partial view in Shared/DisplayTemplates called "ShortDateTime.cshtml" with the following code:

```
@model System.DateTime?

@Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")  : string.Empty
```

The value can be null by the way.

I believe my Template is incorrect, and I need corrections on this please.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateCreated, "ShortDateTime")
```

and in your template:

```
@model System.DateTime?

@(Model.HasValue ? Html.Raw(Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) : null)
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the format to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm". Not sure if I understand why Raw is needed, but it works. Thanks.